# Why was Shurpanakha only disfigured and not killed?

Tags: ramayana

When Shurpanakha goes to eat Sita, Rama restrains her and asks Lakshmana to disfigure her.

> इमाम् विरूपाम् असतीम् अतिमत्ताम् महोदरीम् |
> राक्षसीम् पुरुषव्याघ्र विरूपयितुम् अर्हसि || ३-१८-२०

> "She is freakish, knavish and overtly ruttish, oh, tigerly man, it will be apt of you to deface this paunchy demoness " Thus Rama said to Lakshmana. [3-18-20]

Having slain Tataka when Vishwamitra says to them that slaying unrighteousness women is a justifiable action, why didn’t they treat Shurpanakha similarly?

Comment: Killing a woman is considered a dishonourable act for kshatriyas. While Tāṛakā had already killed many innocent munis, Śūrpanakhā hadn't killed Sītā when was disfigured, she had only attempted to do it. Attempt to murder & committing murder don't attract the same punishment.

Comment: @অনু that can't be it because Vishwamitra says "For the reason of protecting people, a protector always has to execute such deed, either it is ruthless or humane, sinful or vilifying." [1-25-18] He further gives example where others had slain women for bearing ill-intent and not having committed those ill acts.

Comment: "Oh, Rama, the protector of people, we have heard that Indra once eliminated Manthara, the daughter of Virochana, when she wished to annihilate earth, haven't we. [1-25-20]" and And Rama, once Vishnu wiped out even the wife of sage Bhrigu and sage Shukracarya's mother when she wished the world to become one without a governing factor, namely Indra. [1-25-21]"

Comment: You have answered your own question. The cases you showed refer to those whose evil actions threatened the welfare of a large no. of people, not any single particular individual. This goes in line with the policy of statecraft spoken by Bṛhaspati in the Brahmāndapurāṇa (to save multiple people, one can punish a single individual). Meanwhile Śūrpanakhā posed a threat only to Sītā. So it would have been unwise to give such a heavy punishment as big as death to somebody just because they posed a threat to a single individual.

Comment: The second instance is not so. It is only a single individual.

Comment: Yes, monarchs may appear as a single individual, but the monarch's fate affects a large body of people. Besides, the context of the conflict between Viṣṇu & Khyāti is described in detail in the Devībhāgavatapurāṇa. Here Indra, taking advantage of the absence of Śukra (who had gone for tapasyā), attacked the Asuras unawares. So the Asuras took refuge of Śukra's mother Khyāti, who reprimanded Indra for unjustly attacking the defenseless Asuras. Indra defended his acts on grounds of realpolitik, so Khyāti used her powers obtained through chastity to protect the Asuras under her shelter.

Comment: Unable to stand up against Khyāti's power of chastity, Indra approached Viṣṇu & requested him to kill her, which he did. However Khyāti's husband, sage Bhṛgu reprimanded Viṣṇu for resorting to the deplorable act of killing a woman to serve the interests of a person like Indra & cursed Viṣṇu to bear separation from his wife when he would incarnate as a man (which did occur ito Him as Rāma).